# Office 365 for Education says it's unlicensed, even though I provided a valid school email address

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I am a high school student. I downloaded Microsoft Office 365 and provided a valid school email address; according to [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/education/products/office/default.aspx), students who do so should be able to get Office for free. However, when I log into Word with that address, I am still told it Word is "unlicensed" and I can only use basic features of the app. This is very frustrating because I need to use a Word template for an upcoming project. Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

**edit:** Here is the screen I get when I sign into my school account on the Office website:

[image]

It seems to imply I should be able to get Office for free as long as I have a valid school account, w/ or w/o my school's IT dept getting involved in this.

Comment: You'll need to take this up with your school's IT department and/or Microsoft.

Comment: You can only get it for free if your school participates in the Office 365 for education program. Simply using a "school" email address doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @Appleoddity See my update: I'm getting a screen that seems to say the opposite, which is why I posted here.

Comment: Are you prompted when you open word to activate? That is where you should sign in. If not go to the File -> Account menu and sign in / activate under the product information section on the right.

Comment: @Appleoddity I signed in with my school acct, but it still says it's unlicensed.

Comment: I don't have any other answers. Contact your school.

Answer (score 2):

From the FAQ

> Office 365 for Education is a collection of services that allows you to collaborate and share your schoolwork. It’s available for free to teachers who are currently working at an academic institution and to students who are currently attending an academic institution. The service includes Office Online (Word, PowerPoint, Excel, and OneNote), unlimited OneDrive storage

Unless your school signed up for a specific package that bills per user, this is what you get. The 'default' is Some schools allow teachers and students to install the full Office applications on up to 5 PCs or Macs for free. If your school provides this additional benefit, you'll see the Install Office button on your Office 365 home page after you complete sign-up.

So, you'd *need* to check with your IT department, and office365 *online* is the default with a .edu, not the full install.

Amusingly, I know this cause I was looking into it when I *was* the school IT department.